# Pronunciation of the final t in “fait” and “soit”

Tags: usage, prononciation

I need to know why and when I should pronounce the `t` in some words like

> En fait

Always the `t` is pronounced, why?

> Soit

Sometimes the `t` is pronounced, sometimes not. Is it a pronunciation error or does it depend on the context of the sentence ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Le « t » final de « [fait](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fait) » se prononce quand trois conditions sont réunies :

- « Fait » est un nom.
- Il est au singulier.
- On veut l’accentuer, le distinguer du reste ; par exemple, en fin de phrase, ou dans une locution (comme « en fait »).

On prononce la plupart du temps le « t » dans :

> En fait ;
>   de fait.

On ne le prononce jamais dans :

> Mon journal a encore titré sur un fait divers !
>   Parlons des faits !
>   Il fait son devoir.
>   Et toi, l’as-tu fait ?

Le « t » se prononce également pour réaliser une [liaison](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais).

> Prendre fait et cause ;
>   Fait-il beau ?

---

Pour « [soit](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/soit) », ce n’est pas plus simple.

- Employé seul pour faire une concession, on prononce le « t ».

> Soit, j’admets mon erreur.

- Lorsqu’il est utilisé comme conjonction, on ne le prononce pas devant une consonne, mais on le prononce pour faire la liaison.

> Soit aujourd’hui, soit demain.

- Lorsqu’il s’agit du verbe être conjugué, on fait la liaison.

> Il faudrait qu’il soit admis au comité.

- Même si on peut vouloir l’éviter dans certains cas, pour raisons de clarté.

> Soit *a* un réel positif.

Comment: merci beaucoup ! Dans vos exemples avec "soit" avant un voyelle, ce sont des liaisons optionnels, non ?

Comment: Non, je pense qu'elle est obligatoire. sauf dans le premier exemple avec "soit", où il s'agit d'une construction idiomatique (*fair enough*), et dans le dernier, limité au domaine des démonstrations mathématiques. (*let a be a positive real number*)

Comment: Édouard : tu dit que le 't' se prononce quand "fait" est un nom, puis tu donnes ces deux examples où le 't' ne se prononce pas mais "fait" s'utilise comme nom : (1) "Mon journal a encore titré sur un fait divers !" (2) "Parlons des faits !" Peut-tu t'expliquer ?

Comment: Dans le premier cas, la séquence /t d/ n'est pas possible en français (je ne crois pas qu'il existe une langue qui ne fusionnerait pas ces consonnes). Dans le second cas, c'est tout simplement que le -t n'est jamais prononcé au pluriel. Je crois que le -t, en dehors des liaison, est prononcé surtout dans certaines expression. Cette variation n'est pas bien différente de *nombril*, où le -l est communément prononcé en Europe, mais jamais au Québec.

Comment: @bronxbomber92 Il faut que les trois conditions soient réunies. Est-ce plus clair après édition ?

Comment: Ah oui, Ton explication est plus claire maintenant. Merci !

Comment: Pourrais-tu ajouter un exemple dans lequel le T de "fait" est prononcé lorsqu'il se trouve à la fin d'une phrase (sauf les expressions "en fait" / "de fait")?

Answer (score -1):

t not pronounced when it is at the end of a word.
Also, if the word ends with -ts, it is not pronounced.

- tu mets
- il fait
- ...

If it is followed by an -e, or not at the end of the word, it will be pronounced.

- casquette
- petite
- ...

**Note:** if the next word starts with a, e, i, o, u or h, it will be pronounced!

- fait-elle une tarte?

Comment: In general, this is true. However, the final T of "fait" and "soit" is pronounced in some other special cases, as mentioned in the most voted answer.